# UISearchbar not displaying in table

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchbar` that I am trying to display in table header. But for some reasons it is not getting displayed.

I use the following code:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchbar;
```

Even though it does not give any error, I am unable to see the search bar in the table.

I have implemented the `UISearchBarDelegate` as well as tried both plain and grouped tables. I have also tried with nib.

Actually the same thing was working in other project and I imported this into my project, where it is currently not working.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps in your code either `self.tableView` or `searchbar` is nil. This sort of thing often happens when code is brought in from another project but one forgets to hook things up to the nib correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I imported the UIsearchBar code into my project.

I solved it like this:
In your ViewDidLoad method just add these 3 lines before this line (`self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;`)

```
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 280.0f, 44.0f)]; 
searchBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];
```

And make sure in your xib, your searchBar and its delegate is connected to the File's owner.

And it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you set your view controller as a part of tabbar controller, besides "Class" property in IB set the "NIB name" property. It takes me several hours to figure it out.